# Wrong response text is printing in this code, please suggest a way

Tags: json, vba

i am writing exact json path but its showing all wrong inner text.
i am trying this

```
Sub JnewFast()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim json As Object
Dim r, r1, r2, r3 As String

URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=PEL"
With req
.Open "GET", URL, False
.send
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
r = json("priceInfo")("lastPrice")
r1 = json("priceInfo")("intraDayHighLow")("min")
r2 = json("priceInfo")("intraDayHighLow")("max")
r3 = json("priceInfo")("close")
Debug.Print r, r1, r2, r3
End Sub
```

In r3 instead of close its printing "previousClose" please suggest me right way

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem - in the moment I tested, `close` is 0 and that's what is printed in my case.

Comment: The response text of r2 is not printing, its showing some anonymous value may be the max is a math function is cause or something else. Pls check it